# How do I make this image fade on hover?

Tags: html, css, image, fade

I'm trying to make it so when you hover over this `<img>` in the `<div>`, the other `<div>` becomes visible, it works, but, I'm trying to get it to smoothly change to the other `<img>`.
Here is a fiddle of what I mean [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/4/), Thanks for all the help in advance!

If this question has been asked before, I'm sorry for asking it again.  I couldn't find one for what I'm looking for.

Comment: First, the demo needs to be cleaned up. The HTML in the demo has a typo (`<class=`), and the class names used in the CSS don't consisently match the ones used in the HTML (`homebutton` vs `navbutton`). Also, it's a good idea on Stackoverflow to add some of the relevant code to the question itself, in addition to linking to any demos.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your transitions here instead:

```
#nav img
{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sK5q2/6/)***